# use vba code in visual studio ribbon item

Tags: visual-studio, vba, ribbon, powerpoint

I have been couple of days developing some code in vba to detect different types of shapes, create and zip files and so on... The problem is that now I have to create a ribbon item in visual studio 2012 and make a button that makes what I was doing in vba. I create the ribbon, add to it a button and add the code that I had to that button but it have a lot of errors for example in all the rows that I have ActivePresentation. 
Is there any way to use in VS the different object that I was using in VBA? Otherwise someone know what can I use instead?

The code that I have is so long... here is a small piece to make an idea of what I am doing:

```
   Dim sNum As Integer
Dim stri As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim right As Boolean
Dim value As MsoShapeType
Dim it As String
right = True
k = 0
j = 0
it = "Cannot convert the file due to the following problems:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

'ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides


    For i = 1 To sld.Shapes.count

            'Type 1
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoAutoShape Then
                it = it & "AutoShape" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 2
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoCallout Then
                it = it & "Callout." & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 3
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoChart Then
                it = it + "Chart." & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 4
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoComment Then
                'it = it + "a Comment. Type : " & .Type
            End If

            'Type 5
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoFreeform Then
                it = it + "Freeform." & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 6
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoGroup Then
                it = it + "Group." & vbNewLine

            ' If it's a group them iterate thru
            ' the items and list them

                it = it & vbCrLf & "Comprised of..."
                'For Ctr = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
                '    it = it & vbCrLf & _
                 '       .GroupItems(Ctr).Name & _
                '        ". Type:" & .GroupItems(Ctr).Type & vbNewLine
                'Next Ctr

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 7
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                it = it + "Embedded OLE Object" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 8
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoFormControl Then
                it = it + "Form Control" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 9
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoLine Then
                'it = it + "a Line. Type : " & .Type
            End If

            'Type 10
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
                'it = it + "a Linked OLE Object. Type : " & .Type
                'With .LinkFormat
                '    it = it & vbCrLf & "My Source: " & _
                '        .SourceFullName
                'End With
            End If

            'Type 11
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
                it = it + "Linked Picture" & vbNewLine
                'With .LinkFormat
                '    it = it + it & vbCrLf & "My Source: " & _
                '        .SourceFullName
                'End With

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 12
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
                it = it & "OLE Control Object" & vbNewLine

                'right = False
            End If

            'Type 13
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoPicture Then
                it = it & "Embedded picture" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 14
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                'it = it & "text placeholder (title or regular text--" & _
                 '    "not a standard textbox) object." & _
                 '    "Type : " & .Type

                  '   right = False
            End If

            'Type 15
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoTextEffect Then
                'it = it + "WordArt (Text Effect). Type : " & .Type
            End If

            'Type 16
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoMedia Then
                it = it & "Media object .. sound, etc" & vbNewLine
                'With .LinkFormat
                  '  it = it & vbCrLf & " My Source: " & _
                  '  .SourceFullName
                'End With

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 17
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoTextBox Then
                'it = "a Text Box."
            End If

            'Type 18 = msoScriptAnchor, not defined in PPT pre-2000 so we use the numeric value
            'Case msoScriptAnchor
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 18 Then
                it = it & "ScriptAnchor" & vbNewLine


                right = False
            End If

            'Type 19 = msoTable, not defined in PPT pre-2000 so we use the numeric value
            'Case msoTable
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 19 Then
                'it = " a Table. Type : " & .Type
            End If

            'Type 19 = msoCanvas, not defined in PPT pre-2000 so we use the numeric value
            'Case msoCanvas
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 20 Then
                it = it + "Canvas" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 21 = msoDiagram, not defined in PPT pre-2000 so we use the numeric value
            'Case msoDiagram
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 21 Then
                it = it + "Diagram" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 22 = msoInk, not defined in PPT pre-2000 so we use the numeric value
            'Case msoInk
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 22 Then
                it = it + "Ink shape" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If

            'Type 23 = msoInkComment, not defined in PPT pre-2000 so we use the numeric value
            'Case msoInkComment
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 23 Then
                it = it + "InkComment" & vbNewLine

                right = False
            End If


            'Type -2
            If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoShapeTypeMixed Then
                it = "Mixed object (whatever that might be)" & nvNewLine

                right = False
            End If

    Next i
    Next
```

Comment: See my other reply.  VBA is not VB.NET ... it won't work in Visual Studio.  Leave the code in PPT, save it as a PPTM, then open the PPTM in one of the various freely available ribbon editors and add the necessary ribbon code to make buttons that call your VBA subroutines.